# How can I use AudioContext on Dart 2.16 and plus?

Tags: dart, web-audio-api, dart-html

How can I use **AudioContext** on Dart 2.16 ? Because I couldn't import the dart:web_audio library.

Comment: The link below has the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71712835/how-can-i-get-native-mediastreamtrack-from-webrtc-mediastreamtrackweb-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this class by implementing it.
For this, you have to install the [js_bindings](https://pub.dev/packages/js_bindings/install) package.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_webrtc/flutter_webrtc.dart' as webrtc;
import 'package:dart_webrtc/src/media_stream_track_impl.dart' as track_impl;
import 'package:js_bindings/js_bindings.dart' as js_bindings;
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;
import 'dart:js_util' as js_util;

class JsAudioContext {
  js_bindings.AudioContext? audioContext;
  js_bindings.MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode? destinationNode;
  JsAudioContext() {
    audioContext = js_bindings.AudioContext();
  }

  void createMediaStreamDestination() {
    destinationNode = audioContext?.createMediaStreamDestination();
  }

  void connect(webrtc.MediaStreamTrack? trackWeb) {
    track_impl.MediaStreamTrackWeb mediaStreamTrackWeb =
        trackWeb as track_impl.MediaStreamTrackWeb;
    html.MediaStreamTrack htmlTrack = mediaStreamTrackWeb.jsTrack;
    var sourceStream = audioContext?.createMediaStreamSource(
        js_bindings.MediaStream([htmlTrack as js_bindings.MediaStreamTrack]));
    sourceStream?.connect(destinationNode!);
  }

  webrtc.MediaStreamTrack getMixedTrack() {
    List<dynamic> outputTrack =
        js_util.callMethod(destinationNode!.stream, 'getTracks', []);

    webrtc.MediaStreamTrack rtcTrack = track_impl.MediaStreamTrackWeb(
        outputTrack.toList()[0] as html.MediaStreamTrack);
    return rtcTrack;
  }
}
```

Comment: js_bindings for all platform or  only for flutter web?